# Is there the way to reach the final box - GRAPH

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

There is the problem:
The first man 'g' (who starts first) has to reach the final box 'e', so that the second man 'l' (whenever he do) could't catch the first man. The men can go left, right, up, down or can stay.

For example:

```
Input:
6 7
RRRRRRR
R_e___R
R_____R
R_RRR_R
R_gRl_R
RRRRRRR
```

The answer is "YES" because there is the way (Left, Up, Up, Up, Right).

How this problem can be implemented?

I'm using BFS and DFS.
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 32;
char a[MAX][MAX];
int used[MAX][MAX], m1[MAX][MAX], m2[MAX][MAX];;

int movesx[8] = {-1, 1, 0, 0};
int movesy[8] = { 0, 0, -1, 1};

int n, m, c = 0, flag = 0;

struct pc {
    int x, y;
};

pc li, ga, fi;

queue <pc> q;
void BFS1(pc v) {

    pc from, to;
    memset(m1,0,sizeof(m1)); m1[v.y][v.x] = 0;
    memset(used, 0, sizeof(used));

    q.push(v); used[v.y][v.x] = 1;
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        from = q.front(); q.pop();

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            int x = from.x + movesy[i], y = from.y + movesx[i];
            if( (a[y][x] == ' ' || a[y][x] == 'g' ) && !used[y][x]) {
                used[y][x] = 1;
                m1[y][x] = m1[from.y][from.x] + 1;
                pc temp;
                temp.x = x;
                temp.y = y;

                q.push(temp);
            }

        }
    }
}

void BFS2(pc v) {

    pc from, to;
    memset(m2,0,sizeof(m2)); m2[v.y][v.x] = 0;
    memset(used, 0, sizeof(used));

    q.push(v); used[v.y][v.x] = 1;
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        from = q.front(); q.pop();

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            int y = from.y + movesy[i], x = from.x + movesx[i];
            if( (a[y][x] == ' ' || a[y][x] == 'l' ) && !used[y][x]) {
                used[y][x] = 1;
                m2[y][x] = m2[from.y][from.x] + 1;
                pc temp;
                temp.x = x;
                temp.y = y;

                q.push(temp);
            }

        }
    }
}

void DFS(pc v) {
    used[v.y][v.x] = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {

        int x = v.x + movesx[i], y = v.y + movesy[i];

        if(a[y][x] == 'e') {
                c = 1;
                flag = 1;
                return;
        }

        if( (a[y][x] == ' ' ) && !used[y][x] && m2[y][x] < m1[y][x] && flag == 0 ) {
            pc temp;
            temp.x = x;
            temp.y = y;

            DFS(temp);
        }

    }
}

int main() {
        c = 0, flag = 0;
        memset(used, 0, sizeof(used));
        memset(a, 'R', sizeof(a));
        cin >> n >> m;
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            getline(cin, s);
            for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
                a[i][j] = s[j];
                if(a[i][j] == 'g') {
                    ga.x = j;
                    ga.y = i;
                }
                else if(a[i][j] == 'l') {
                    li.x = j;
                    li.y = i;
                }
                else continue;

            }
        }

        BFS1(li);
        BFS2(ga);

        memset(used, 0, sizeof(used));

        DFS(ga);
        if(c == 1) {
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "NO" << endl;
        }

}
```

Here is the second code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 32;
char a[MAX][MAX];
int used[MAX][MAX], m1[MAX][MAX], m2[MAX][MAX];;

int an[1002][MAX][MAX];

int movesx[8] = {-1, 1, 0, 0, 0};
int movesy[8] = { 0, 0, -1, 1, 0};

int n, m, c = 0, flag = 0;

struct pc {
    int x, y;
};

pc li, ga;

void functionD() {

    for(int z = 1; z <= 1000; ++z) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {

                if(an[z - 1][i][j] == 1) {
                    int x, y;
                    for(int k = 0; k < 5; ++k) {

                        x = j + movesx[k];
                        y = i + movesy[k];


                        if(x < m && y < n && x >= 0 && y >= 0) {

                            if(a[y][x] != 'R' && a[y][x] != 'e') {
                                an[z][y][x] = 1;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }


}

void DFS(pc v, int k) {
    used[v.y][v.x] = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {

        int x = v.x + movesx[i], y = v.y + movesy[i];

        if(a[y][x] == 'e') {
                c = 1;
                flag = 1;
                return;
        }
        if(an[k][y][x] == 0 && a[y][x] != 'R' && !used[y][x] && flag == 0 && k <= 1000) {
            pc temp;
            temp.x = x;
            temp.y = y;
            DFS(temp, k + 1);
        }

    }
}

int main() {
    int nn; cin >> nn;

    for(int z = 0; z < nn; ++z) {
        c = 0, flag = 0;
        memset(used, 0, sizeof(used));
        memset(a, 'R', sizeof(a));
        cin >> n >> m;
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            getline(cin, s);
            for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
                a[i][j] = s[j];
                if(a[i][j] == 'g') {
                    ga.x = j;
                    ga.y = i;
                }
                else if(a[i][j] == 'l') {
                    li.x = j;
                    li.y = i;
                }

            }
        }
        an[0][li.y][li.x] = 1;

        functionD();



        DFS(ga, 1);


        if(c == 1) {
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "NO" << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT (By Jarod42):

I found a tricky map which failed:

```
9 9
RRRRRRRRR
R...Rg..R
R.RlRRR.R
R.R...R.R
R.RRR.R.R
R.Re....R
R.R.RRR.R
R.......R
RRRRRRRRR
```

`l` cannot protect both accesses to `e`.

or even simpler

```
RRRRRRRRRR
R...RRRRRR
R.R...RRRR
RlReR...gR
R.R...RRRR
R...RRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRR
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: @Jarod42 some test cases are wrong. Only 70% is completed and I can't check where is the problem because test cases are big.

Comment: Can you please explain the idea? That is too much code.

Comment: @IVlad Ok, I'm using BFS1 function to find distances from 'l' to all boxes (but 'R' and 'e') and BFS2 function to find distances from 'g' to all boxes (but 'R'). Than I'm using DFS.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you explain it?

Comment: Are you unable to show us an example of failure because it is _too big_, or because it is _known only to an online judge?_

Comment: Like I said I can't find the problem. But the service can. Because there is big  inputs i can't find failure.

Comment: Maybe try Beta's updated answer.

Comment: @James: I added a tricky map where path is possible, but your answer false.

Comment: In your `DFS` you forget to restore `used[v.y][v.x] = 0` for next iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the DFS. Just test whether `l` can reach `e` before `g` can. If he can, then he can catch `g`, otherwise `g` wins.

(And beware of redundancy in your code; BFS1 and BFS 2 are almost identical, and could be combined into a single function.)

**EDIT:** The OP has added (a link to) new information: `l` cannot enter `e`.

The correction to this algorithm is obvious, if inelegant. Consider the rooms surrounding `e`; if there is one that `g` can reach before `l`, then `g` wins.

There may be other catches in the linked problem statement; the OP can state the problem he wants answered *in the question itself*. We don't like "link only" questions here.

Comment: -1, this is wrong: imagine a wall that separates the matrix in half and `e` part of this wall. `l` and `g` can be on separate sides of the wall, with `l` closer to `e`. This means `l` can reach it faster, but can't catch `g`.

Comment: @IVlad: Do you mean that `g` cannot reach `e` at all?

Comment: No, I mean something like `g  _____ e __  l`. `l` cannot pass through `e`. And even if he could, I'm pretty sure your solution would still be wrong in general.

Comment: @IVlad: Who says `l` cannot pass through `e`?

Comment: The problem statement the OP linked to: "Means LeChuck can go up, down, left,right one room at a time (as soon as it’s not "R" or "e") or stay, in each time unit". Even if he could, you should at least explain why you think this might work, but in this case it's clear that this solution is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'l' can't reach the 'e' box.

Comment: @IVlad: 1) The link was added after I posted, 2) the correction to my algorithm is obvious, 3) you seem to be saying that you're pretty sure my solution is wrong even if `l` can enter `e` (and downvoting) without actually having a counterexample.

Comment: I don't need a counterexample, you need at least an intuitive proof, not just "do X", and I'll gladly upvote.

Comment: @IVlad: I cannot make my proof intuitive to you; believe me, I wish I could.

Comment: Ok, counterexample: `R R R R R R R R / _ _ _ _ E _ _ l / g _ _ _ _ _ _ _`. `l` is closer to `E`, but it cannot block `g` if `g` decides to go up and then straight towards `E`.

Comment: @IVlad: That is not a counterexample. If `l` can enter `e` (as you conceded above with *"even if he could"*, try to keep track of these things), then `l` can head straight left and catch `g`. And even if `l` cannot enter `e` (keep track now) look at my edit: `g` can reach the room just left of `e` before `l` can, so `g` wins. I wish I could disprove things as easily as you seem to think you can.

Comment: I missed your edit. It's worth trying your edited solution I think. As for disproving things, the burden of proof lies on the person making the proposal. If you don't attempt to explain **why** you're suggesting something, it is reasonable to assume that it is wrong.

Comment: @Jarod42: You have illustrated -- quite competently -- one of the ambiguities in the wording of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have first to create a map distance from each accesses to `e`.

Then it is a minmax (or alpha-beta):

- if `g` current position in one map-distance is less than `l` current position is same map-distance, `g` wins.
- if `l` has less or equal distance in all maps distance, `g` loses.
- else `g` has to use one of its valid map to reach the goal, `l` counters with its maps (or stands).

(Note: `g` has no reasons to stand as `l` may do the same and we are at the same point).

(Edit: Note: in provided link, it seems that the secure path has to be chosen statically, so the dynamic part (3rd bullet) is a loose for `g`)